# SUMIF nonblank cells in intrerrupted range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, sumifs

I have 3 columns of data which may or may not have values in them, and I want their sum.

Basically I want to make the following formula work:

`SUMIF(D3&P3&AB3,"<>")`

Setting the range as D3:AB3 will not work, as I have various other values in between and I only want the D, P, and AB columns summed.

I know I could use nested IFs but this is just a sample and I actually have a lot more columns to sum up.

For example D3 would have a number value, P3 would be blank and AB3 would be blank. In that case I just want to see D3 in my cell

### EDIT

It works with `=SUM(D3,P3,AB3)`, but not by `=D3+P3+AB3` and I'd like to understand why

Comment: are all in `row 3` numeric or is there an example you can show? as you say, its not possible to combine like you have done With `sumif`

Comment: Yes all are in the same row

Comment: Why not just use `=SUM(D3,P3,AB3)`...

Comment: my question was more whats in that row since you cant use `sumif`on that entire row? Are the numeric or not in that row, any static that can be canceld?

Comment: There are indeed numerics in the row, as well as some string values

Comment: Wow thanks Mrig it was too obvious, I was unaware that excel ignores string values with SUM

Comment: Apprently `=D3+P3+AB3` gives a #VALUE error, but with SUM it works, anyone knows why? @Mrig

Comment: See [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-correct-a-VALUE-error-15E1B616-FBF2-4147-9C0B-0A11A20E409E?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Comment: You can post an answer and accept it if you want the question to be marked as "solved".

Comment: 'You can accept your answer in 2 days'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
=SUM(D3,P3,AB3)
```

`SUM` function will add numbers in the cells ignoring text and blanks.